# Slide div down when user scrolls up the page

Tags: jquery, css, slidedown, slideup

I'm trying to make a function that slides a divison tag up when scrolling down the page and then slide the divison down when the user scrolls up the page at the given position.

I have made it slide up after my specific value, but can't figure out how to slide it down again when the user scrolls up. I'm trying to make the upper part of my header's content hide on scroll down and show when scroll up.

Another problem that I get is when you refresh the page after you scrolled down, it will trigger the slide again.

HTML:

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="header-top">
        <div class="logo-top">Westring</div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="img/logo-icon.png" alt="Westring-kbh logo" width="70" height="70"></a>
    <nav class="menu">
        <div class="menu_item">
            <a href="#" class="menu_links"><span class="hidetext">Grafisk </span>Design<span class="menu_line"></span></a>
            <div class="menu_item_fix1">
                <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item"><span class="link_border_effekt">Branding</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item">Produktion</a>
                <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item">Ngo'er</a>
                <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item">Kampagner</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu_item">
            <a href="#" class="menu_links">Web<span class="menu_line"></span></a>
            <div class="menu_item_fix2">
                <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item">Design</a>
                <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item">Shops</a>
                <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item">Optimering</a>
                <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item">Udvikling</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu_item">
            <a href="#" class="menu_links">Marketing<span class="menu_line"></span></a>
            <div class="menu_item_fix2">
                <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item">Seo</a>
                <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item">Sem</a>
                <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item">Sociale medier</a>
                <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item">Direct mail</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu_item">
            <a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="social_section">
        <a href="#" class="social_expand">
            <div class="facebook">
                <p class="social_share">Facebook</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="social_expand">
            <div class="twitter">
                <p class="social_share">Twitter</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.header-top {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #F8F8F8;
}
.logo-top {
    font-size:40px; 
    color:#333;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
    width: 96%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
.logo {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
}
/******* Menu ********/
.menu {
    float: left;
    display: inherit;
}
.menu_item {
    float: left;
    width: 110px;
    height: 70px;
    border-right: 1px solid #303F4A;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.menu_links::after {
    content: " :";
    color: #171F29;

}
.menu_links {
    position: relative;
}
.menu_line {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 15px;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #161E28;
    height: 40px;
    opacity: 0;
}
.menu_item:hover .menu_line {
    opacity: 1;
}
.menu_item:hover .menu_links::after {
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    content: " :";
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
.menu_item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    width: 110px;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu_item:hover .menu_expand_item {
    opacity: 1;
}
.menu_item:nth-child(1):hover {
    width: 490px;
}
.menu_item:nth-child(2):hover,
.menu_item:nth-child(3):hover {
    width: 460px;
}
.menu_item_fix1 {
    width: 490px;
}
.menu_item_fix2 {
    width: 460px;
}

.menu_item .menu_expand_item {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 13px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top: 19px;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 13px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.menu_expand_item:hover {
    background-color: #171F29;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: auto;
}

/******* Social share in menu ********/
.social_section {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    display: inherit;
}
.social_expand {
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    height: 70px;
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #303F4A;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.social_expand:hover {
    width: 130px;
}
.social_share {
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 50px;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 70px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.social_expand:hover .social_share {
    opacity: 1;
}
.facebook {
    background: url(../img/facebook_icon.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.twitter {
    background: url(../img/twitter_icon.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 40){
            $(".header-top").slideUp();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is the [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/2k5ncgfc/)

Comment: `else $(".header-top").slideDown();`

Comment: Thank you, works great:) 

I still have a problem when you refresh the page at the bottom, then the function triggers again. Is there a way to control this? So the function only runs from top and when scroll to top.